# Receive Ajax and display output in a Photo?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image

How to Receive Ajax and display output in a Photo?
Images should be displayed inside the div tag
After each of Bayer text, change the text to change the photo content
The photos displayed are written in the form

this code

> ```
> <script>
> function AjaxRequest() {
>     var xmlhttp = null;
>     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
>         // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
>           xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
>     } // else // code for IE6, IE5
>     return xmlhttp;
> }
>
> function ajaxAction() {
>     var font_category = document.getElementById("ajaxField").value;
> var xmlHttp = AjaxRequest();
>     xmlHttp.open("POST" , "ajax.php?message=" + message , true);
>     xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
>         if(xmlHttp.readyState == 1)
>             response.innerHTML = "Loading...";
>         if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
>             response.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
>     }
>     xmlHttp.send(null);
> }
> </script>
>
> <textarea id="ajaxField12" name="message" rows="2" cols="20" value="Send" onchange="javascript:ajaxAction();">
>
> </textarea> 
>
>
> <div id="ajaxResponse" height="42" width="42"> 
> </div>
> ```

Comment: Is there any problem with the code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the photo than use something like this

```
$("document").ready(function(){
$("textarea").on("keyup",function(){ 
      $values=$(this).val();
      $.get("ajax.php?message="+values,function(data){
     $("#ajaxResponse").html("<img src="+data+" height='10' width='10'>");

})

})

})
```

in your serverside

```
 <?php
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT img.src from img WHERE message=?");
    $statement->execute(array($_GET["message"]));
    if($row_count = $statement->rowCount()>0);
       { $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       echo $row["src"];
       }
    ?>
```

You should not use `mysql_*` functions
you should learn about prepared statements and use either PDO or MySQLi. If you cannot decide, Than see the comment or goto [PDO](http://php.net/pdo)

Comment: If you can avoid it, please don't use the `mysql_*` functions, they are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you want to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @vascowhite i am familiar with that but i am just showing.same as our previous comments.May be user is not familiar `PDO` or `mysqli`

Comment: And again, I'll say to you that you shouldn't be teaching people bad/wrong practice. If the OP is not familiar with PDO, then introduce him to it. It is no harder to learn than the mysql_* functions.